# No reconoce nombre de la columna con INNER JOIN en sql server y c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

realice una consulta en c# y al momento de obtener los datos solo me muestra los datos de una tabla pero no reconoce los de la otras tablas porque no reconoce el nombre de la columna.
[image: Imagen de los valores que me devuelve al ejecutar la consulta]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo solo me reconoce las columnas de la tabla principal y no las del inner join que serian codi_cliente y ruc

```
SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(cadena, conexion);
        SqlDataReader registros = comando.ExecuteReader();
        while (registros.Read())
        {
            reporte.total_participantes = 
           int.Parse(registros["tot_participantes"].ToString());
            reporte.total_horas = Double.Parse(registros["tor_horas_capacitadas"].ToString());
            reporte.cliente.CodiCliente = int.Parse(registros["codi_cliente"].ToString());
            reporte.cliente.RucCliente = (registros["ruc"].ToString());
        }
        conexion.Close();
```

me reconoce todos los campos con normalidad menos codi_cliente y ruc

Comment: ya encontré el error, me faltaba inicializar el Objeto "Cliente", reporte.cliente = new Cliente();

Comment: pero no tenias ningna mensaje de error? al asignar propiedades de un objeto sin instanciar. El problema que describes no se relaciona en nada con la solucion que mencionas